# parsing children/grandchildren in python

Tags: python, xml

is there a simple way how to parse this xml and create data table from this with nodes in header, please?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CenoveUdaje bez_mj="n" mesic="3" rok="2017" katuze_kod_cu="693936" xmlns="http://services.cuzk.cz/xsd/cenoveUdaje/1.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://services.cuzk.cz/xsd/cenoveUdaje/1.0 http://services.cuzk.cz/xsd/cenoveUdaje/1.0/cenoveUdaje.xsd" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Rizeni id="47739998010">
    <cisloRizeni>V-782/2017-306</cisloRizeni>
    <datumPodani>2017-02-24T10:32:00</datumPodani>
    <datumZplatneni>2017-03-24T08:36:48</datumZplatneni>
    <praresKod>306</praresKod>
    <listiny>
      <Listina id="39180964010">
        <cena>1</cena>
        <mena>CZK</mena>
        <listinaTyp>Smlouva kupní</listinaTyp>
      </Listina>
    </listiny>
    <nemovitosti>
      <Nemovitost id="56063439010" typ="PAR">
        <katuzeKod>693936</katuzeKod>
        <text>1386/41</text>
        <popis>č. 1386/41 Jáma</popis>
        <bod>
          <gml:Point gml:id="P.47739998010.PAR.56063439010" srsName="EPSG:5514">
            <gml:pos>1163440.34 782060.87</gml:pos>
          </gml:Point>
        </bod>
        <teleso id="674643306">
          <cislo>17</cislo>
        </teleso>
      </Nemovitost>
    </nemovitosti>
  </Rizeni>
</CenoveUdaje>
```

I've tried to parse it on my own, but I don't know how to get to children and grandchildren nodes neither the data table.

```
# xml parse
tree = etree.parse('XMLs/2017_03.xml')
root = tree.getroot() 
rizeni = tree.findall('{http://services.cuzk.cz/xsd/cenoveUdaje/1.0}Rizeni')
print(rizeni)
print(rizeni[0].attrib)

print("cisloRizeni: "+root[0][0].text)
print("datumPodani: "+root[0][1].text)
print("datumZplatneni: "+root[0][2].text)
print("praresKod: "+root[0][3].text)
```

The final data table should look like this:

> cisloRizeni;datumPodani;datumZplatneni;praresKod;listiny:cena;listiny:mena;listiny:listinaTyp;nemovististi:katuzeKod;...
> "V-782/2017-306";"2017-02-24T10:32:00";"2017-03-24T08:36:48";306;1;"CZK";"Smlouva kupní";693639;...

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by 'table'?

Comment: using modules like `lxml` or `BeautifulSoup` you should have objects `child`, `children`, which you can use together `child.children` to get `granchildren` for one `child`. Or in `for`-loop `for child in children: print( child.children )` to grandchildren for all `children`

Comment: what result do you expect? Show expected table in question.

Comment: as I remeber in some modules you can get children using `for child in node` or `list(node)`.

Comment: @furas I've added the example of output table. Regarding the modules you are referring to. I'll try it.

Comment: Your final table isn't clear: given the xml in the question, how many columns and how many rows will the table have?

Comment: 14 columns and 1 row regarding this example, but in the end I'll work with many xmls with many records, so there will be n-rows.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to get to something resembling the table in your question, and you'll have to modify the code from there.

For this, we'll use pandas and lxml. I modified the xml a bit to include two identical `<Rizeni>` tags inside the `<CenoveUdaje>` parent, just to show how it works. Again, you will obviously have to modify it to fit your own data:

```
from lxml import etree
import pandas as pd
rizeni = """[your xml above, modified as explained]"""
doc = etree.XML(rizeni.encode())

#collect the column names:
cols = [d.tag.split('}')[1] for d in doc.xpath('*[local-name()="Rizeni"][1]//*')]

#collect the data:
rows = []
for r in doc.xpath('*[local-name()="Rizeni"]'):
    row = []
    for item in r.xpath('.//*'):
        info = (item.text if len(item.text.strip())>0 else "None")
        row.append(info)

    rows.append(row)

#place it all in a dataframe:
pd.DataFrame(rows,columns=cols)
```

Output (sorry about the formatting):

```
cisloRizeni     datumPodani     datumZplatneni  praresKod   listiny     Listina     cena    mena    listinaTyp  nemovitosti     Nemovitost  katuzeKod   text    popis   bod     Point   pos     teleso  cislo
0   V-782/2017-306  2017-02-24T10:32:00     2017-03-24T08:36:48     306     None    None    1   CZK     Smlouva kupní   None    None    693936  1386/41     č. 1386/41 Jáma     None    None    1163440.34 782060.87    None    17
1   V-782/2017-306  2017-02-24T10:32:00     2017-03-24T08:36:48     306     None    None    1   CZK     Smlouva kupní   None    None    693936  1386/41     č. 1386/41 Jáma     None    None    1163440.34 782060.87    None    17
```

From here you can add and drop columns using standard pandas methods.

Comment: Thanks :-) but you are saying something about modifying xml. """[your xml above, modified as explained]""". Can you be more specific please?

Comment: @MonikaFeigler I'm referring to " I modified the xml a bit to include two identical `<Rizeni>` tags inside the `<CenoveUdaje>` parent, just to show how it works" in the answer.